# How do I update files created by phoenix.gen.html in the Phoenix Framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've created a simple user model using `phoenix.gen.html` with the schema produced in `models/user.ex` as follows.

```
    schema "users" do
      field :name, :string
      field :email, :string
      field :bio, :string
      field :dislikes_turnips, :boolean

      timestamps
  end
```

Along with `models/user.ex`, the database table has been created along with the views, controllers and templates.

I'd like to update my User Model by changing one field and adding another to the create something like the following.

```
schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :bio, :string
    field :likes_turnips, :boolean
    field :turnips, :integer

    timestamps
  end
```

Is there a mix task or similar to update the related database table, views, controllers and templates in one go?

And if not, what would be the recommended process to change/update these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make the updates to your scheme as you have done. However you will also need to generate a migration so your database table reflects this:

`mix ecto.gen.migration change_turnips_on_users`

You should have a new file in `priv/repo/migrations` that you need to modify (you an read more about migrations [in the docs](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html):

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.ChangeTurnipsOnUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:users) do
      add :turnips, :integer
    end

    rename table(:users), :dislikes_turnips, to: :likes_turnips
  end
end
```

You will also need to update the following things:

- `form.html.eex` for your user
- The `changeset/2` function that was generated for your user model to reflect the new fields.